# Adding new connection into ConnectionStrings.config gives "exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'property:changed' event"

Tags: configuration

After I added new connection string into `ConnectionStrings.config` file, I cannot log into Sitecore and getting this exception:

[image]

**Exception textually:**

```
> Server Error in '/' Application.

> One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'property:changed' event.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

> Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'property:changed' event.

> Source Error: 

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

> Stack Trace: 


> [AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'property:changed' event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +422
   Sitecore.Data.Properties.PropertyStore.RaiseEvent(String name, Object[] parameters) +85
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.IsTicketExpired(Ticket ticket, Boolean useProlongation) +357
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.GetTicket(String ticketId, Boolean returnExpired) +118
   Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DefaultTicketManager.IsTicketValid(String ticketId) +49
   Sitecore.Shell.Web.ShellPage.IsLoggedIn(Boolean returnAfterLogin) +314
   Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.SecurePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +22
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4088

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found root cause of this issue.

Database that should correspond to connection string was not present on SQL Server.

I was trying to add new publishing target to my Sitecore instance, therefore I have added new connection string for secondary web database.

I have forgotten to attach database into SQL Server and hence exception from Question.

Unfortunately, exception shown to the Sitecore user is not so descriptive and lead me nowhere.
Indication for resolution was found in these exceptions in Sitecore error log:

> ManagedPoolThread #2 12:56:18 ERROR Exception processing remote events from database: web_secondary
>   Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   Message: Login failed for user 'webuser'.
>   Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.DataProviderCommand..ctor(IDbCommand command, DataProviderTransaction transaction, Boolean openConnection)
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<CreateCommand>b__0()
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.b__0()
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.NullRetryer.Execute[T](Func`1 action, Action recover)
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.CreateReader(String sql, Object[] parameters)
>      at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataApi.<CreateObjectReader>d__27`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Sitecore.Eventing.EventQueue.ProcessEvents(Action`2 handler)
>      at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseQueuedEvents()

Hopefully this will help somebody with same exception. This is possible solution for you :)

Answer (score 2):

i had this when i restored my PROD master DB to my local DEV environment.

ensure that your DB user **masteruser**

has both **DataReader** and **DataWriter** permissions.

once allocated you should be able to log into the experience platform

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO [masteruser];

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [masteruser]
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [masteruser]
```